# how to get an application supported languages programmatical

Tags: java, android

How to get the languages supported by an application?

For an Android project, we can know which languages the app supports by looking at the project directory(res/values). Is there a way to get the message at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the code below but it's working with API 24 above

```
val lang = applicationContext.resources.configuration.locales.toLanguageTags()
val langs = lang.split(",".toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. The code will return a list which displays in the device's "Language preferences "  view.

Comment: that's not what i need.    For an application, if it contains non-English strings such as FR or CN resource, when you set the device language to FR, the application's view will display FR strings. I just want to know how many languages resources that the application contains at runtime.